# C++ Running actual code from file without compiling it

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to make a program which can read code from a file (similar to an [interpretor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) but not as complex) store it into a linear list and then execute it when needed.

This is what i want this "interpretor" to know:

```
variable declaration
array declaration
for, while, if control structures 
input and output files (output files can be opened in append mode)
non recursive functions
```

Because i execute it command by command i can stop/start at a specific number of commands executed which is helpful when trying to do more at the same time (similar to [multithreading](https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading)) and for this reason, i will name the class `_MINI_THREAD`. Here are the declarations of the `struct COMMAND` and `class _MINI_THREAD`:

```
struct COMMAND
{
    unsigned int ID;
    char command_text[151];
    COMMAND* next;
    COMMAND* prev;
};
class _MINI_THREAD
{
public:
    void allocate_memory()
    {
        while (start_of_list == NULL)
            start_of_list = new (std::nothrow) COMMAND;
        while (end_of_list == NULL)
            end_of_list = new (std::nothrow) COMMAND;
        start_of_list -> prev = NULL;
        start_of_list -> next = end_of_list;
        end_of_list -> prev = start_of_list;
        end_of_list -> next = NULL;
    }
    void free_memory()
    {
        for(COMMAND* i=start_of_list -> next;i!=end_of_list;i=i->next)
            delete i -> prev;
        delete end_of_list -> prev;
        delete end_of_list;
    }
    bool execute_command(unsigned int number_of_commands)
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<number_of_commands;i++)
        {
             /*match id of current command pointed by the cursor with a function from the map*/
             if (cursor==end_of_list) return false;
             else cursor=cursor->next;
        } 
        return true;
    }
    bool if_finished()
    {
        if (cursor==end_of_list)return true;
        else return false;
    }
    unsigned int get_ticks()
    {
        return ticks_per_loop;
    }
    void set_ticks(unsigned int ticks)
    {
        ticks_per_loop = ticks;
    }
private:
    unsigned int ticks_per_loop;
    COMMAND* cursor=NULL;
    COMMAND* start_of_list=NULL;
    COMMAND* end_of_list=NULL;
};
```

I also try to keep the syntax of the "invented code" from the source files as close as possible to the c/c++ syntax but sometimes i placed a new parameter because it makes verification a lot easier. Please notice that even the `while` has a name so that i can manage nested loops faster.

Here is an example i came up with:

```
Source_file.txt

int a;
input_file fin ("numbers.in");
output_file fout ("numbers.out");
while loop_one ( fin.read(a,int,skipws) )
{
    fout.print(a,int);
    fout.print(32,char); /*prints a space after each number*/
}
close_input_file fin;
close_output_file fout;

/*This code is supposed to take all numbers from the input file and */
/* move them into the output file */
```

In the real program the object `thread1` of class `_MINI_THREAD` contains a dinamically allocated list (i will display it as an array for simple understanding)

```
_MINI_THREAD thread1;
/*read from Source_file.txt each command into thread1 command array*/
thread1.commandarr={
                    define_integer("a"),
                    open_input_file("numbers.in",fin),
                    open_output_file("numbers.out",fout),
                    define_label_while("loop_one",fin.read()),  /*if the condition is false the `cursor` will jump to labe_while_end*/
                    type_to_file(fout,a,int),
                    type_to_file(fout,32,char),
                    label_while_return("loop_one"), /*returns the cursor to the first line after the while declaration*/
                    label_while_end("loop_one"), /*marks the line after the while return point*/
                    close_input_file("numbers.in",fin),
                    close_output_file("numbers.out",fout),
                   };
/*the cursor is already pointing at the first command (define_integer("a"))*/
/*this will execute commands until the cursor reaches the end_of_list*/
while(thread1.execute_commands(1))NULL; 
thread1.free_memory();
```

Now my problem is actually implementing the `IF_CONTROL_STRUCTURE`. Because you may want to type `if (a==b)` or `if (foo())` etc... and i don't know how can i test all this stuff.

I somehow managed to make the `cursor` move accordingly to any structure (`while`,`do ... while`,`for` etc) with the idea of [`labels`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Label_(computer_science)) but still i cannot check the condition each structure has.

Comment: Are you trying to write an interpreter?

Comment: i am already lost at your first snippet. The `while` that waits should come after calling `execute_command` otherwise you infinitely keep calling `execute_command` and the threads never finish them

Comment: Not a full one! But yes kind of. I actually just want it to do simple algorithms.

Comment: Why do you need to write your own interpreter? C++ has a good interop with many scripting languages, most notably `lua`.

Comment: It almost sounds like you want to build a scripting engine into your program.  One thing people do is use Lua to allow arbitrary scripts to be run.

Comment: @user463035818 sorry for my bad positioning but the execute_command() will stop when the cursor reaches the end of the list. Take a look at the link at the end of my question.

Comment: you want to execute commands until the threads are finished (doing somethingelse?) ? Or do you want to make the threads execute commands and wait till they are finished with that?

Comment: @SergeyA i have to write it by hand because its a school project and i have to explain every bit of this concept. Also the teach wont allow this kind of stuff.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: "What's the most solid way of having the if, for and while into that list?"  I'd use an AST structure instead of a linear list.

Comment: @PasserBy sounds like yes, but it seems that x is the question here and the y is some crude restrictions made up by the teacher

Comment: @user463035818 im not sure what you asked. Well all that execute stuff will be wrapped into an interface (console but still interface) so i can say that they simply run until they reach the end of their _COMMAND list. Nothing more

Comment: Since this is a school project, you need to pay attention to what the instructor provided in terms of solution parameters. Your interpreter should have its own runtime environment. You should be able to define appropriate mechanisms to pass parameters.

Comment: i am just saying that I understand that code as `while (threads are not finished)  { give them more stuff to do; }` if thats really what it is supposed to be the loop will never end. Either it should be `give them some stuff to do;  while(they are not finished) { wait for them to finish}` or it is me who is on the completely wrong track

Comment: @user463035818 More like `wait for them to finish` and then `give them more stuff`. Sorry i think i confused you. I'll make a quit bastebin with more details so you can understand.

Comment: This is also where I ask you to provide a [mcve]. From what I can tell, you are asking about an interpreter of an invented language, and you are stuck on how to implement control structures. Everything else can go away.

Comment: Since you are interpreting in place, you need to parse the condition of the `if`, decide if it is true or false, then go inside the body if true, and not if false.

Comment: sorry if this sounds rude, but I dont really want to see more details. I would rather join passerby and say the question would be better with a bit less details while focussing on the `if` `for` and `while` you are asking about (but currently they dont appear in the code)

Comment: ok i will work on that and update the question.

Comment: Your comments in that code are completely redundant and effectively just noise - comments along the line of "++i; // increment i" don't add any actual value; rather they can confuse and they are bound to become obsolete/incorrect over time. Don't document *what* code does (that's obvious from the code itself), document *why* code does something.

Comment: I improved my answer. But you need to read stuff before coding. Most of the code in your question is junk, so throw it to the trash bin. You absolutely need to at least read SICP before touching your program again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to write some [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) (probably using some [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode)). Read more about [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)).

Writing well a good interpreter is not a trivial task. Consider using some existing one, e.g. [Lua](http://lua.org/), [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Neko](https://nekovm.org/), [Python](https://www.python.org/), [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/), .... and take some time to study their free software implementation.

Otherwise, spend several months reading stuff, notably:

- **[SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) is an absolute must to read** (and freely downloadable).
- the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)
- [*Programming Language Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/)
- [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces)
- about the [SECD machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SECD_machine)
- the [*GC handbook*](http://gchandbook.org/)

Notice that an entire book (at least) is needed to explain how an interpreter works. See also relevant [SIGPLAN](http://www.sigplan.org/) conferences.

Many (multi-thread friendly) interpreters have some [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock). A genuinely multi-threaded interpreter (without any GIL) is very difficult to *design* (what exactly would be its [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) ???), and a multi-threaded garbage collector is also very difficult to implement and debug (consider using an existing one, perhaps [MPS](https://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/) or [Boehm's GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/)).

So "your simple work" could require *several years* of full-time work (and could get you a PhD).

### a simpler approach

After having read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and becoming familiar with some [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language))-like language (probably some [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)), e.g. thru [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/)), you could decide on some simpler approach (basically a tiny Lisp interpreter which you could code in a few hundred lines of C++; not as serious as full-fledged interpreters mentioned before).

You first need to define on paper, at least in English, the [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)) and the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of your scripting language. Take a strong inspiration from Lisp and its [S-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression). You probably want your scripting language to be [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) (so your [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) would be values of your languages), and it would have (like Lisp) only *expressions* (and no statements). So the conditional is ternary like C++ [`? :`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

You would represent the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of your scripting language as some C++ data structure (probably some `class` with a few virtual methods). [Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) some script file into an AST (or a sequence of AST, maybe feed to some REPL) is so classical that I won't even explain; you might use some parser generator -improperly called [compiler-compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) (like [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [lemon](https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/doc/lemon.html)).

You would then at least implement some [`eval`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval) function. It takes two arguments *Exp* and *Env*: the first one, *Exp*, is the AST of the expression to be evaluated, and the second one, *Env* is some binding environment (defining the binding of local variables of your scripting language, it could be as simple as a stack of mapping from variables to values). And that `eval` function returns some value. It could be a member function of your AST class (then *Exp* is `this`, the receiver ....). Of course ASTs and values of your scripting language are some [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (which you might, if so wished, represent as a class hierarchy).

Implementing recursively such an `eval` in C++ is quite simple. Here is some pseudo code:

```
eval Exp Env :
  if (Exp is some constant) {
     return that constant }
  if (Exp is a variable Var) {
     return the bounded value of that Var in Env }
  if (Exp is some primitive binary operator Op /* like + */
      with operands Exp1 Exp2) {
     compute V1 = eval Exp1 Env
     and V2 = Exp2 Env
     return the application of Op /* eg addition */ on V1 and V2
  }
  if (Exp is a conditional If Exp1 Exp2 Exp3) {
     compute V1 = eval Exp1 Env
     if (V1 is true) {
       compute V2 = eval Exp2 Env
       return V2
     } else { /*V1 is false*/
       compute V3 = eval Exp3 Env
       return V3
     }
  }
  .... etc....
```

There are many other cases to consider (e.g. some `While`, some `Let` or `LetRec` which probably would *augment* `Env`, primitive operations of different arities, `Apply` of an arbitrary functional value to some sequence of arguments, etc ...) that are left as an exercise to the reader. Of course some expressions have [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) when evaluated.

Both *SICP* and *Lisp In Small Pieces* explain the idea quite well. Read about [meta-circular evaluators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-circular_evaluator). Don't code without having read SICP ...

The code chunk in your question is a design error (even the `MINI_THREAD` thing is a mistake). Take a few weeks to read more, throw your code to the thrash bin, and start again. Be sure to use some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system (I strongly recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/)).

Of course you want to be able to interpret recursive functions. There are not harder to interpret than non-recursive ones.

---

<sup>PS. I am very interested by your work. Please send me some email, and/or publish your tentative source code.</sup>

Comment: I thank you for the linked documentation though i only need this interpreter to do simple algorithms. Thats why i didnt go straight to searching a real interpreter and started to build my own.

Comment: The simplest is to embed some *existing* interpreter.

Comment: Re, "What exactly would be its REPL?" Why would having the ability to run code in new threads be incompatible with having a REPL? Does Python not have both threads and a REPL? Ruby? Lisp?...

Comment: Most such REPLs are conceptually for a single-threaded interpreters (so, from the REPL  point of view, all other threads are in the background)

Comment: C++ is conceptually a single-threaded language, but from the point of view of any given thread, all other threads are in the background.  Java is conceptually a single-threaded language, but from the point of view of any given thread, all other threads are in the background.  Ruby is conceptually... Lisp is conceptually... I guess I do not understand what you meant when you said, "a _genuinely_ multi-threaded interpreter."